# does linearly dependency or independency have a symbol?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

whenever we talk about the concept, we always write "$\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_r$ linearly independent" which is a really long line. it takes so much time to write and read.

is there an abbreviation? like if I write $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_r$ as $S$ and write "linearly independent" as $[S]$ or whatever? is there a formal symbol?

Comment: None that I know of. I'm not sure it's really worth a symbol. Seems like most of the time you just call a basis into existence anyway.

Comment: You can define that notation $[S]$ once and for all and use it. Mathematics is not a programming language that needs an ANSI C committee  to define which notation should compile or not.

Comment: In case that $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are $m-$vectors, you could use $\mathrm{V} = \{ \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ once in the beginning of your work and later just write $\det (\mathrm{V}) \neq 0$ for independency.